# Where can i find customeditors in JBPM 6

Tags: workflow, drools, jbpm, drools-guvnor

I am upgrading my workflow system from jbpm 5.4 to JBPM 6.1 . I implemented custom editors for Groups in Jbpm 5.4 using this link;
http://surdilovic.wordpress.com/2012/07/03/custom-input-editors-in-jbpm-designer/
There is a customeditors file in global area in drools-guvnor jbpm 5.4. Can anyone tell me how can i find this customeditors file in Jbpm 6? I am working for this for hours. Please can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in the "global" folder of your project. If you switch your Project Explorer to "Repository View" and click on the top-level global folder you will find the customeditors json config file. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmtqG.png for reference.

Comment: I found customeditors as you described. Then I edited that file for custom group editors as below;        { "editors":{
 "Actors" : "designer/customeditors/sampleactorseditor.html",
 "GroupID":"designer/customeditors/samplegroupeditor.html"
}}   . I followed every step as described  in http://surdilovic.wordpress.com/2012/07/03/custom-input-editors-in-jbpm-designer/  article. In Jbpm 5.4 , it's working fine , but it's not working in jbpm 6.1